# Conflict with * in data entry per terminal (sys.argv) Python

Tags: python, terminal

I have created a basic calculator. But when entering `*` in the terminal that is not selected as a `'*'` character. Instead, enter `'*'` select as character `*`

Code

```
import sys

def calc(x, y, op):
    elif op == '*':
        z = x * y
        return z

print(calc(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]), sys.argv[3]))
```

> Input  2 2 *
>
> Output None

Instead

> Input  2 2 '*'
>
> Output 4

So, I wanted to see what the terminal picks up.

Code

```
import sys

a = sys.argv[1]

print(a)
```

> Input  '*'
>
> Output *

Seems like Calculator code..

Then..

> Input  *
>
> Output 01.py

01.py It is a file that contains this folder

My question is ... what does it really mean * in sys.argv for python?

Comment: [PYTHON: How to pass asterisk (\*) as command line argument](//stackoverflow.com/q/24327078)

Comment: This is nothing to do wth Python. The shell expands * before passing it to your script.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You have enough rep to vote to close as a duplicate instead of just posting a link.